# Special characters in robot framework log.html

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Robot framework log.html file shows special characters in strings.

Keyword:

```
Log     ${result}    console=yes   level=INFO
```

Output from log.html:

```
'\r\r\nServer listening on UDP port 9004\r\r\nReceiving 1470 byte datagrams\r\r\nUDP buffer size: 160 KByte (default)\r\r\n------------------------------------------------------------\r\r\n[ 4] local 192.168.200.190 port 9004 connected with 10.42.12.2 port 47325\r\r\n[ ID] Interval
```

When I'm using Log To Console keyword it's logging the same string to console like this:

```
Server listening on UDP port 9004

Receiving 1470 byte datagrams

UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)

------------------------------------------------------------

[  4] local 192.168.200.190 port 9004 connected with 10.42.12.2 port 47325

[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams

[  4]  0.0- 4.0 sec  46.8 MBytes  98.1 Mbits/sec   0.128 ms  227/33602 (0.68%)
```

How to show this string in log.html file in the same format as in a console without special characters '\n' and '\r'?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to replace all \n with br tag and enable the html option in the Log keyword.

```
${resultDL}    String.Replace String    ${result}    \n    <br>
${resultDL}    String.Remove String    ${resultDL}    \r
Log     ${resultDL}    html=yes    level=INFO
```